# Correct credentials, but segfault etc. disconnect immediately after connection

Tags: xrdp, rdp

Ubuntu vm, trying remote desktop from windows. It used to work. port 3399 TCP is open on the firewall. If I give incorrect credentials, I get an error, which is expected.

With correct credentials, this is what I see in syslog:

```
Nov  3 13:22:49 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp[545813]: (545813)(140583346861888)[DEBUG] xrdp_00085415_wm_login_mode_event_00000001
Nov  3 13:22:49 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp[545813]: (545813)(140583346861888)[INFO ] Cannot find keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00004009.ini
Nov  3 13:22:49 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp[545813]: (545813)(140583346861888)[INFO ] Cannot find keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00004009.ini
Nov  3 13:22:49 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp[545813]: (545813)(140583346861888)[INFO ] Loading keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00000409.ini
Nov  3 13:22:49 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp[545813]: (545813)(140583346861888)[WARN ] local keymap file for 0x00004009 found and doesn't match built in keymap, using local keymap file
Nov  3 13:23:06 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp[545813]: (545813)(140583346861888)[DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350
Nov  3 13:23:06 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp-sesman[544519]: (544519)(140061298837056)[INFO ] A connection received from ::1 port 33208
Nov  3 13:23:06 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp[545813]: (545813)(140583346861888)[INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sesman connect ok
Nov  3 13:23:06 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp[545813]: (545813)(140583346861888)[DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sending login info to session manager, please wait...
Nov  3 13:23:06 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp[545813]: (545813)(140583346861888)[DEBUG] return value from xrdp_mm_connect 0
Nov  3 13:23:06 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp-sesman[544519]: (544519)(140061298837056)[INFO ] ++ created session (access granted): username themainuser, ip ::ffff:171.76.87.116:30367 - socket: 12
Nov  3 13:23:06 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp-sesman[544519]: (544519)(140061298837056)[INFO ] starting Xorg session...
Nov  3 13:23:06 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp-sesman[544519]: (544519)(140061298837056)[DEBUG] Closed socket 9 (AF_INET6 :: port 5911)
Nov  3 13:23:06 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp-sesman[544519]: (544519)(140061298837056)[DEBUG] Closed socket 9 (AF_INET6 :: port 6011)
Nov  3 13:23:06 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp-sesman[544519]: (544519)(140061298837056)[DEBUG] Closed socket 9 (AF_INET6 :: port 6211)
Nov  3 13:23:06 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp[545813]: (545813)(140583346861888)[INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: login successful for display 11
Nov  3 13:23:06 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp-sesman[544519]: (544519)(140061298837056)[DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET6 ::1 port 3350)
Nov  3 13:23:06 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp-sesman[545831]: (545831)(140061298837056)[INFO ] calling auth_start_session from pid 545831
Nov  3 13:23:06 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp[545813]: (545813)(140583346861888)[DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: started connecting
Nov  3 13:23:06 theVMHost-FT1-VM systemd[1]: Started Session c26 of user themainuser.
Nov  3 13:23:06 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp-sesman[545831]: (545831)(140061298837056)[DEBUG] Closed socket 7 (AF_INET6 ::1 port 3350)
Nov  3 13:23:06 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp-sesman[545831]: (545831)(140061298837056)[DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET6 ::1 port 3350)
Nov  3 13:23:06 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp-sesman[545833]: (545833)(140061298837056)[INFO ] /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg :11 -auth .Xauthority -config xrdp/xorg.conf -noreset -nolisten tcp -logfile .xorgxrdp.%s.log
Nov  3 13:23:06 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp[545813]: (545813)(140583346861888)[INFO ] lib_mod_log_peer: xrdp_pid=545813 connected to X11rdp_pid=545833 X11rdp_uid=1000 X11rdp_gid=1000 client_ip=::ffff:171.76.87.116 client_port=30367
Nov  3 13:23:06 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp[545813]: (545813)(140583346861888)[DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: connected ok
Nov  3 13:23:06 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp-sesman[545831]: (545831)(140061298837056)[CORE ] waiting for window manager (pid 545832) to exit
Nov  3 13:23:06 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp[545813]: (545813)(140583346861888)[DEBUG] xrdp_mm_connect_chansrv: chansrv connect successful
Nov  3 13:23:06 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp[545813]: (545813)(140583346861888)[DEBUG] Closed socket 18 (AF_INET6 ::1 port 33208)
Nov  3 13:23:07 theVMHost-FT1-VM kernel: [8389216.354762] xfce4-session[545897]: segfault at 2c ip 000055b1ee0e82c4 sp 00007ffee7436458 error 4 in xfce4-session[55b1ee0d1000+1d000]
Nov  3 13:23:07 theVMHost-FT1-VM kernel: [8389216.354777] Code: 48 83 c4 08 4c 89 e7 5d 41 5c e9 27 bc fe ff 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 48 83 c4 08 5d 41 5c c3 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa <8b> 47 2c c3 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa 8b 47 28 c3 0f 1f
Nov  3 13:23:08 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp-sesman[545831]: (545831)(140061298837056)[CORE ] window manager (pid 545832) did exit, cleaning up session
Nov  3 13:23:08 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp-sesman[545831]: (545831)(140061298837056)[INFO ] calling auth_stop_session and auth_end from pid 545831
Nov  3 13:23:08 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp-sesman[545831]: (545831)(140061298837056)[DEBUG] cleanup_sockets:
Nov  3 13:23:08 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp[545813]: (545813)(140583346861888)[DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET6 ::ffff:10.0.0.4 port 3389)
Nov  3 13:23:08 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp-sesman[545831]: (545831)(140061298837056)[DEBUG] cleanup_sockets: deleting /run/xrdp/sockdir/xrdp_chansrv_audio_out_socket_11
Nov  3 13:23:08 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp[545813]: (545813)(140583346861888)[DEBUG] xrdp_mm_module_cleanup
Nov  3 13:23:08 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp-sesman[545831]: (545831)(140061298837056)[DEBUG] cleanup_sockets: deleting /run/xrdp/sockdir/xrdp_chansrv_audio_in_socket_11
Nov  3 13:23:08 theVMHost-FT1-VM systemd[1428]: home-themainuser-thinclient_drives.mount: Succeeded.
Nov  3 13:23:08 theVMHost-FT1-VM systemd[875]: home-themainuser-thinclient_drives.mount: Succeeded.
Nov  3 13:23:08 theVMHost-FT1-VM systemd[1]: home-themainuser-thinclient_drives.mount: Succeeded.
Nov  3 13:23:08 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp[545813]: (545813)(140583346861888)[DEBUG] Closed socket 19 (AF_UNIX)
Nov  3 13:23:08 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp-sesman[545831]: (545831)(140061298837056)[DEBUG] cleanup_sockets: deleting /run/xrdp/sockdir/xrdpapi_11
Nov  3 13:23:08 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp[545813]: (545813)(140583346861888)[DEBUG] Closed socket 20 (AF_UNIX)
Nov  3 13:23:08 theVMHost-FT1-VM xrdp-sesman[544519]: (544519)(140061298837056)[INFO ] ++ terminated session:  username themainuser, display :11.0, session_pid 545831, ip ::ffff:171.76.87.116:30367 - socket: 12
```

I restarted xrdp. No luck

Did a `chmod +x .xsession` on the user's home directory. No luck there neither!

Any help/ideas please?

Thanks

**Update:** This is what i see in the .xsession-errors of the user's home directory :-(

```
Xsession: X session started for theVMUser at Sat Nov  4 12:28:48 IST 2023
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:11.0
localuser:theVMUser being added to access control list
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USER=theVMUser
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HOME=/home/theVMUser
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XRDP_PULSE_SINK_SOCKET=xrdp_chansrv_audio_out_socket_11
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XRDP_PULSE_SOURCE_SOCKET=xrdp_chansrv_audio_in_socket_11
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PULSE_SCRIPT=/etc/xrdp/pulse/default.pa
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LOGNAME=theVMUser
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/snap/bin
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XRDP_SOCKET_PATH=/run/xrdp/sockdir
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:11.0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANG=C.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting UID=1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHELL=/bin/bash
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XRDP_SESSION=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PWD=/home/theVMUser
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SGX_AESM_ADDR=1
xfce4-session-Message: 12:28:48.703: SSH authentication agent is already running
gpg-agent[66999]: WARNING: "--write-env-file" is an obsolete option - it has no effect
gpg-agent: a gpg-agent is already running - not starting a new one

(xfce4-session:66993): xfce4-session-WARNING **: 12:28:48.706: gpg-agent returned no PID in the variables

(xfce4-session:66993): xfce4-session-WARNING **: 12:28:48.708: xfsm_manager_load_session: Something wrong with /home/theVMUser/.cache/sessions/xfce4-session-ApnaVikas-FT1-VM:11, Does it exist? Permissions issue?

(xfwm4:67001): xfwm4-WARNING **: 12:28:48.904: Unsupported GL renderer (llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0, 256 bits)).

(xfwm4:67001): xfwm4-WARNING **: 12:28:49.944: Failed to connect to session manager: Failed to connect to the session manager: IO error occured opening connection
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Gdk-Message: 12:28:49.959: xfwm4: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :11.0.
```

Comment: This seems to be a known issue with trying to start an xrdp session where the same user is already logged in to a local graphical session - see for example [XRDP session close immediately #2258](https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/2258#issuecomment-1170951572)

Comment: thanks @steeldriver but am not able to figure out. I have added an update from the error log. Can't decipher that in terms of any action(s) that i need to do :-(

Comment: If the linked bug report is correct, there doesn't seem to be any action you can take aside from making sure you do not have a concurrent local session - perhaps try creating a separate user for rdp logins if you need to be logged in locally as well?